# Clocks from different timezones on the Taskbar

Tags: windows-10

I'm looking for a way to display clocks on windows 10 taskbar, from different timezones.

I know that there is a similiar option, but I want the clock on the taskbar, without clicking on the primary clock and watch it there.

Anuko World Clock's feature should be good, but it says that taskbar clock not supported in Windows 10.
T-Clock would be also good but there is no second clock option.

Thank you! :)